# Extjs tree store set leaf property value based on children property

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect, extjs5

I am using a TreeStore to load data that looks like this:

`{
    "categories": [{
        "text": "Ext JS",
        "expanded": "true",
        "categories": [{
            "text": "app",
            "categories": [{
                "text": "Application.js",
                "categories": "null"
            }]
        },
        {
            "text": "button",
            "expanded": "true",
            "categories": [{
                "text": "Button.js",
                "categories": "null"
            },
            {
                "text": "Cycle.js",
                "categories": "null"
            },
            {
                "text": "Split.js",
                "categories": "null"
            }]
        }
        ]
    }]
}`

What I want is to set the leaf property to true or false if the categories property is null or not. 
My model looks like this :

```
Ext.define('TestTree.model.MyModel', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
requires: [
    'Ext.data.field.Boolean'
],
fields: [
    {
        name: 'text'
    },
    {
        type: 'boolean',
        name: 'leaf'
    }
]
```

});

The idea was to use the calculate config of the leaf field for that but if I try to use data.get('categories') I get  *Field leaf depends on undefined field get* and if I try to define the field *categories* in my model an use data.categories, nothing happens.
I don't know what I am missing!
My store looks like this:

```
Ext.define('TestTree.store.MyTreeStore', {
extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
requires: [
    'TestTree.model.MyModel',
    'Ext.data.proxy.Ajax',
    'Ext.data.reader.Json'
],
constructor: function(cfg) {
    var me = this;
    cfg = cfg || {};
    me.callParent([Ext.apply({
        storeId: 'MyTreeStore',
        autoLoad: true,
        model: 'TestTree.model.MyModel',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'resources/data/treeData.json',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'categories'
            }
        }
    }, cfg)]);
}
```

});

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your model with the following init method:

```
Ext.define("Files", {
    extend : "Ext.data.Model",
    fields : [{
         name: 'categories'
    },{
        name: 'leaf',
        convert : function(value, record) {
            return record.get('categories') == 'null';
        }
    }]
});
```

This should fix your issue, and here is a fiddle so you can take a look: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/gq8

Comment: Thank you Guilherme ! It worked. Do you know if why it does not work using the "calculate" or "convert" configs? Can you give me an example of this.data being different of 'object'? Thanks again :).

Comment: if you add a `console.log(this.data);` before the if statement you will see that sometimes `this.data` comes back as a string and I wanted to discard these values.. And sorry, but I don't see calculate or convert being valid configs of the `Ext.data.Model` class. If you can, provide a fiddle with what you were trying to do. Thanks

Comment: The calculate and convert configs are valid for 'Ext.data.field.FieldView'. I will try to add an example on fiddle this week. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi, I just updated the model to use the convert method like you asked.

Comment: Hi, I just updated my implementation and it seems to work. Thank you! Just one remark: the null value in a JSON string generally comes without commas so you should return record.get('categories') === null :).

Answer (score 0):

I used `calculate` instead of `convert`.

From the [doc](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.2-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.field.Field)

> Using calculate is the simplest and safest way to define a calculated field.

So the code becomes

```
Ext.define("Files", {
    extend : "Ext.data.Model",
    fields : [{
         name: 'categories'
    },{
        name: 'leaf',
        calculate : function(data) {
            return data.categories === null;
        },
        depends: ['categories']
    }]
});
```